# Horizontal Flow Chart with Images

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I am wanting to create a standalone flowchart with images and arrows. Here is the mockup: 
[image: Sequence Flowie]

Each box would be an image.

Comment: Nothing. I don't know where to start. I have done a vertical flowchart a long time ago, but it did not include images.

Comment: You can include image inside nodes by `\includegraphics`. Now please add an example code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Alright. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc} 
\tikzset{shifted by/.style={to path={($(\tikztostart)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$)
 -- ($(\tikztotarget)!#1!-90:(\tikztostart)$)}}, 
 shifted by/.default=2pt,standard edge/.style={very thick,-latex}, 
 back and forth between/.style args={#1 and #2}{insert path={
  #1 edge[standard edge,-latex,shifted by] #2 #2 edge[standard edge,shifted by] #1}}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
boot/.style={draw,thick,align=center,label=below:#1 Lessons}]
 \node[boot=20] (EAB) {Elementary\\ Algebra\\ Bootcamp};
 \node[below right=1cm and 0cm of EAB.south,boot=12] (FM) {Fractions\\
 Mini Camp};
 \node[right=2cm of EAB,boot=20] (IAB) {Intermediate\\ Algebra\\ Bootcamp};
 \node[below right=1cm and 0cm of IAB.south,boot=9] (FM2) {Factoring\\
 Mini Camp};
 \node[above right=0.5cm and 2cm of IAB.east,boot=20] (CAB) {College\\ Algebra\\ Bootcamp};
 \node[below right=0.5cm and 2cm of IAB.east,boot=14] (SB) {Statistics\\ Bootcamp};
 \node[right=2cm of CAB,align=center] (CAB') {3 months\\ 60 lessons};
 \node[right=2cm of SB,align=center] (SB') {3 months\\ 54 lessons};
 \draw[back and forth between={(EAB.south east) and (FM.50)},
 back and forth between={(IAB.south east) and (FM2.50)}];
 \draw (EAB) edge[standard edge] (IAB)
 (IAB) edge[standard edge] (CAB) (IAB) edge[standard edge] (SB);
 \path (CAB) -- (CAB') node[midway,scale=2]{$=$}
 (SB) -- (SB') node[midway,scale=2]{$=$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Are there any other options for the array styles? And is there a way to space between the back and forth arrows?

Comment: @BuddyKingsGalletti Sure. This is all controlled by the `shifted by/.default=2pt,` key. Try e.g. `\draw[shifted by/.default=5pt,back and forth between={(EAB.south east) and (FM.50)},
 back and forth between={(IAB.south east) and (FM2.50)}];`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone! Here was my final result:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, shapes, arrows, arrows.meta}


\definecolor{ballblue}{rgb}{0.34, 0.66, 0.96}
\definecolor{xyzgreen}{rgb}{0.55, 0.77, 0.38}

\tikzset{shifted by/.style={to path={($(\tikztostart)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$)
 -- ($(\tikztotarget)!#1!-90:(\tikztostart)$)}}, 
 shifted by/.default=5pt,standard edge/.style={very thick,-latex}, 
 back and forth between/.style args={#1 and #2}{insert path={
  #1 edge[standard edge,-latex,shifted by] #2 #2 edge[standard edge,shifted by] #1}}} 



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily, boot/.style={draw,thick,align=center,label=below:#1 Lessons}]

    \node[boot=20, circle, fill=ballblue, draw=none] (EAB) {\includegraphics[width= 60px]{EABC_course_icon_2019.jpg}};

    \node[below right=1.5cm and 1cm of EAB.south,boot=12, rectangle, fill=ballblue, draw=none] (FM) {\includegraphics[width= 60px]{FRACMC_icon_CC2019.jpg}};

    \node[right=2cm of EAB,boot=20, circle, fill=ballblue, draw=none] (IAB) {\includegraphics[width= 60px]{IABC_course_icon_2019.jpg}};

    \node[below right=1.5cm and 1cm of IAB.south,boot=9, rectangle, fill=ballblue, draw=none] (FM2) {\includegraphics[width = 60px]{FACMC_icon_CC2019.jpg}};

    \node[above right=1cm and 2.5cm of IAB.east,boot=20, circle, fill=ballblue, draw=none] (CAB) {\includegraphics[width = 60px]{CAPRCBC_course_icon_2019.jpg}};

    \node[below right=1cm and 2.5cm of IAB.east,boot=14, circle, fill=ballblue, draw=none] (SB) {\includegraphics[width= 60px]{SBC_course_icon_2019.jpg}};

    \node[right=2cm of CAB,align=center] (CAB') {3 months\\ 60 lessons};

    \node[right=2cm of SB,align=center] (SB') {3 months\\ 54 lessons};



    \draw[-latex, line width=1.25mm, color=xyzgreen] (EAB) to (IAB)
    (IAB) edge[standard edge, line width=1.25mm, color=xyzgreen] (CAB);
    \draw[-latex, line width=1.25mm, color=xyzgreen] (IAB) to (SB);
    \path (CAB) -- (CAB') node[midway,scale=2]{$=$}
    (SB) -- (SB') node[midway,scale=2]{$=$};

    \draw[-latex, line width=1.1mm, shifted by, color=xyzgreen] (EAB.south east) to[bend right=35] (FM.north);
    \draw[-latex, line width=1.1mm, shifted by, color=xyzgreen] (FM.north) to[bend right=35] node[below,rotate=60] {} (EAB.south east);

    \draw[-latex, line width=1.1mm, shifted by, color=xyzgreen] (IAB.south east) to[bend right=35] node[above,rotate=60] {} (FM2.north);
    \draw[-latex, line width=1.1mm, shifted by, color=xyzgreen] (FM2.north) to[bend right=35] node[below,rotate=60] {} (IAB.south east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bootcamp Flowie]