# How to I create a horizontal flow chart in tikz with five sequential images in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-arrows, flow-charts

I would like to create a flowchart similar to this below:

IMG 1 --------> IMG 2 ------> IMG 3 ....

caption 1 ... caption 2 ... caption 3.....

I have tried following [Horizontal Flow Chart with Images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485182/horizontal-flow-chart-with-images), but I am not quite sure how to get the captions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that you looking for something like this:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\tikzset{ar/.style = {very thick, gray, -{Triangle[angle=90:3pt 2]}}}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt} 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} XcXcX @{}}
\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-duck}
    &   \tikz\draw[ar] (0,0) -- + (0.6,0);
        &   \includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-duck}
            &   \tikz\draw[ar] (0,0) -- + (0.6,0);
                & \includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-duck}    \\
\caption{First figure}
    &   &   \caption{Second figure}
            &   &   \caption{Third figure}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**

If you prefer to have the images in landscape orientation, you have to add `rotating` package and use `sidewaysfigure` instead of the `figure`-environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{rotating} % <--- new


\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}[h] % <--- changed

... < table body 

    \end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this so the page is horizontal? Thank you!

Comment: @C.Schmidt-Padilla, you mean that page with figure is in landscape orientation? Yes, it is possible. You need to add the `rotating` package and than instead of `figure` use `sidewaysfigure` environment. I will ad this to answer asap.